# Dynamically selecting column and aggregate function in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I have a query in Linq that needs to be dynamically adjustable based on some values a user selects in a form. My query looks as follows:

```
(from data in DbContext.CoacheeData
 group data by data.UserId into g
 select new LeaderboardEntry
 {
     Name = g.FirstOrDefault().UserName,
     Value = g.Sum(data => data.Steps),
 });
```

I would like two aspects of this query to be dynamic:

- The aggregate function used to calculate the value (could be sum, average or max)
- The column used to calculate the value (see below)

I've been trying - and failing - to use Linq expressions for this, but I keep getting runtime errors. I'm pretty new at Linq, so I'm probably doing something stupid.

Below is an excerpt from the CoacheeData class. If it helps, all of the properties are numbers. All floats even, with the exception of Steps.

```
public class CoacheeData
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    //Each of these properties should be selectable by the query
    public int Steps { get; set; }
    public float Distance { get; set; }
    public float CaloriesBurned { get; set; }
    //...etc
}
```

### EDIT: I was asked what I'd tried, below are the most relevant things I think:

```
Func<CoacheeData, int> testLambda = (x) => x.Steps;

//Used inside the query like this:
Value = g.Sum(testLambda),
```

This throws an exception ("Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025."), which I think is normal because you can't use lambda's directly in Linq to SQL. Correct me if I'm wrong. So I tried with an expression:

```
Expression<Func<CoacheeData, int>> varSelectExpression = (x) => x.Steps;

//And in the query:
Value = g.Sum(varSelectExpression.Compile()),
```

Throws the same error 1025, which is working as intended because the Compile() call changes the expression into a lambda again, in my understanding. However I can't omit the Compile() call, because then the Linq code doesn't compile. No idea how to fix this.

I tried similar things for the sum, I suspect my errors (and the solution) will be comparable. I will add more info later if needed.

Comment: Quite a lot of stuff, I'll add the most relevant things to the main post

Comment: What type is `Value` supposed to be? `double`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DynamicLINQ library. These allow you to construct your queries using strings. Here are a few links (some of these may be extensions of each other - didn't look too much into each).

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd looked into it before, and if there's no alternative, I'd consider it, but I'd prefer something type safe.

Comment: I understand. I have had to use these libraries to create queries for reporting where the user had the ability to set their own criteria and select fields. These libraries worked extremely well for that case. I also tried what you did with expressions and this was 100x easier. However, I also understand wanting strongly typed.

Comment: It's not just that, but also that I'm sure it should be possible to do it with expressions and I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong. Abandoning them because I'm unable to fix it feels like a cop-out.

Answer (score 0):

A type safe solution is to build the `GroupBy` expression dynamicaly. My component [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) has been designed for this.

It introduced the concept of *cube* in a LINQ query.

Just define a cube with 1 dynamic dimension and 1 dynamic measure.

```
class MyCubeItem
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public double Value { get; set; }
}

class MyCube : ICubeDefinition<CoacheeData, MyCubeItem>
{
  public string DimensionName { get; set; }
  public string AggregateName { get; set; }
  public string AggregateOperator { get; set; }

  public Expression<Func<CoacheeData, string> Name
  {
    get
    {
      switch (DimensionName)
      {
        case "UserId":
          return x => x.UserId;
        ...
      }
    }
  }

  public Expression<Func<CoacheeData, string> Value
  {
    get
    {
      switch (AggregateName)
      {
        case "Steps":
        switch (AggregateOperator)
        {
          case "Sum":
            return items => items.Sum(x => x.Steps);
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use the `QueryByCube` LINQ extension method:

```
var result = DbContext.CoacheeData
  .QueryByCube(new MyCube() {
     DimensionName = "UserId",
     AggregateName = "Steps",
     AggregateOperator = "Sum"
   })
  .Select(x => new LeaderboardEntry() {
     Name = x.Name,
     Value = x.Value
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. In order to do this you need to only use the extension methods when passing in expressions. EF's linq to sql does not support passing an expression into an expression.

Note that the following works best if its one numeric datatype. I'm using `float`;

```
var baseQ  = (from data in DbContext.CoacheeData
              group data by data.UserId into g
              select g);
Expression<Func<CoacheeData,float> expression;
switch(propName){
    case "Distance": 
         expression = x=> x.Distance; break;
    case "CaloriesBurned":
         expression = x=>x.CaloriesBurned; break;
}

switch(aggregateFn) {

     case AggregateFn.Sum: 
          return baseQ.Sum(expression);
     case AggregateFn.Max: 
          return baseQ.Max(expression);   

     //...      
}
```

`AggregateFn` is an enum in this example.